# How to change the program for finding a perfect number by its number in the sequence so that it is in one line?

Tags: kotlin

This program:
By perfect number, searches for its number in the sequence of all
perfect numbers in ascending order

Code:

```
    fun PerfectDigits(n:Int): Boolean {
    var i = 1;
    var k = false;
    var m = 0;
    while(i<n)
    {
        if(n%i == 0) m+=i;
        i++;
    }
    if(m==n) k=true
    return k;
}
fun main() {
    var s = readLine();
    var c:Int = 0;
    var i:Int = 0
    if(s!=null) {
        while (c < s.toInt()) {
            i++;
            if (PerfectDigits(i)) {
                println(i)
                c++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that brevity shouldn't be the most important goal.  It can be a useful skill, and when all else is equal shorter code does tend to be easier to read, understand, and modify — but all else is never equal, and clarity, simplicity, robustness, flexibility (and in certain cases, performance) are all arguably more important.

Comment: @gidds Tell this to my teacher, who, when he saw Kotlin and its capabilities, said to shorten the code as much as possible

Comment: Writing one-liners can certainly be a useful exercise, and teach you techniques you wouldn't otherwise have used.  And sometimes one-liners _are_ as clear, robust, obvious, and/or performant as longer code.  (In Alex T.'s answer, the one-liner explains what a perfect number is in a much clearer way than the longer versions.)  But don't assume it's automatically better than a longer function; as I said, you have to balance brevity with those other goals, and sometimes a more long-winded approach is better overall.

Comment: I completely agree with you and hold the same opinion, just in this case there was a message to write the code as expressive as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always do something like this:

```
fun Int.isPerfectNumber() = (1 until this).filter { this % it == 0 }.sum() == this
```

But this is not really efficient. To make it a bit better, you should return `false` when:

- The number is odd (there are no known odd perfect numbers).
- The number is smaller than 6 (the lowest known perfect number) (or at least check if not negative, since all perfect numbers are positive by definition).

But then, it wouldn't be a true 1 liner:

```
fun Int.isPerfectNumber() = when {
    this < 6 -> false //smallest perfect number
    this % 2 == 1 -> false //no known odd perfect numbers
    else -> (1 until this).filter { this % it == 0 }.sum() == this 
}
```

You would call any of these extension functions like this:

```
5.isPerfectNumber()
//or
val myNumber = 6
myNumber.isPerfectNumber()
```

Comment: Cool! thanks
Can you please tell me why my program displays only the first 4 perfect numbers, and then hangs, what could be the problem?
I tried to change the type to Long, but no results were obtained

Comment: I'd guess because the 5th perfect number is `33.550.336` it has 8 digits. Those are quite a few calculations to be made. I'm at work now so can't test it properly to see there is an actual issue with it, or if it is just slow. I'll be back in around 5-6 hours

Comment: If you can do without var variables and mutable collections it will be super